# use of undeclared type 'GMSMarker' in xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got a crash in ios 9.1 to use google maps. But its working fine in ios 9.0.2. When I run this code in Xcode 7.1 I got use of undeclared type 'GMSMarker' Error message. Kindly helped me...

I am using swift language.

Comment: *When I run this code*  What code do you mean?

Comment: Plz post the error code

Comment: What version of Google maps are you using?